# Computing the period via elliptical integral

Tags: dynamical-systems, elliptic-integrals

> I am having trouble showing that the period (T) of this system can be expressed in terms of an elliptical integral.

Given the dynamical system governed by the differential equation below:

$(1/2)I_O(\dot\theta)^2 - mgDcos(\theta) = (1/2)I_O(\dot\theta_0)^2 - mgD$

when $\dot\theta_0 > \sqrt{4mgD \over I_O}$

where $I_O$ m,  g  and D are constants and $\dot\theta_0$ is the angular velocity when $\theta$ = 0

Show that $T = {4 \over\dot\theta_o} * R(x)$

R(x) is an eliptical integral => $\int_0 ^{\phi\over2}{d\phi \over\sqrt{1-xsin^2(\phi)}}$ where $x = {4mgD \over I_O(\dot\theta_0)^2} < 1$

My attempt:

$\dot\theta=d \theta/ dt = f(\theta) $

$T = \int_0^{2\pi}{{d\theta \over f(\theta)}}$

Doing a bit of algebra will lead to:

$ \dot\theta = \sqrt{{2mgD \over I_O}(cos\theta-1)+(\dot\theta_0)^2}  $

Using the identity $ cos\theta = 1-2sin^2{\theta \over 2}$ gives:

$ \dot\theta = \sqrt{(\dot\theta_0)^2(1-sin^2{\theta \over 2})} $

Now I have :

$T = \int_0^{2\pi}{{d\theta \over \sqrt{(\dot\theta_0)^2(1-sin^2{\theta \over 2})}}}$

Using the transformation $\phi={\theta \over 2}$ will only give me a 2 in the numerator.  I also don't know the "x" comes into play

Comment: You are simply much too sloppy in your computations. There is no way $$\sqrt{{2mgD \over I_O}(cos\theta-1)+(\dot\theta_0)^2}\quad\text{and}\quad\sqrt{(\dot\theta_0)^2(1-sin^2{\theta \over 2})}$$ can coincide.

Answer (score 0):

You made a small error when using the half-angle formula, because the factor $2 m g D/I_O$ has suddenly disappeared. The substitution should read
\begin{equation}
 \sqrt{\frac{2 g m D}{I_O}(\cos \theta - 1) + \dot{\theta}_0^2} = \sqrt{\dot{\theta}_0^2 - 2 \frac{2 g m D}{I_O} \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}} \tag{1}.
\end{equation}
If you now take $\dot{\theta}_0^2$ outside the square root, you obtain from $(1)$
\begin{equation}
 |\dot{\theta}_0^2| \sqrt{1 - \alpha \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}},
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
 \alpha = \frac{4 g m D}{\dot{\theta}_0^2 I_O}.
\end{equation}